# How to draw graph in Latex

Tags: diagrams

Could you please help me to draw this figure in Latex[image]

Thank you so much,

Best

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: This can be easily created using `tikz`: Create some nodes and arrows. https://texample.net/tikz/examples/

Answer (score 2):

Here's my novice attempt at the same.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
 
\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}
 
    \node[draw,
        text width=6cm,
        align=left] at (0,0)
        (health)
        {\textbf{Health}\\- Using modern energy reduces exposure to hazardous pollutants.\\- Avoiding drudgery such as collecting fuelwood improves health condition of, in particular, women and children.\\- Access to electricity enables vaccination and medicine storage by a refrigerator.};
 
    \node[draw,
        text width=6cm,
        align=left] at (8,0)
        (education)
        {\textbf{Education}\\- Lighting appliances enables to study at night.\\- Utilization of modern energy results in freeing up from drudgery and creating time for study.\\- Electricity helps narrow the digital divide through Information Communication Technologies (ICTs).};
        
    \node[draw,
        minimum height=1.5cm,
        text width=3cm,
        inner sep=0pt,
        align=center] at (4,-4)
        (energy)
        {\large{\textbf{Energy}}};
 
    \node[draw,
        text width=6cm,
        align=left] at (0,-8)
        (income)
        {\textbf{Income}\\- Enterprise development through electrification creates job.\\- Mechanization in industry achieves higher productivity.\\- Small-scale energy system in rural areas generates local industry.};
 
 
    \node[draw,
        minimum width=2cm, 
        text width=6cm,
        minimum height=1cm, 
        align=left] at (8,-8)
        (environment)
        {\textbf{Environment}\\- Reduction in use of fuelwood pretends deforestation.\\- Use of efficient electric appliances saves energy consumption.\\- Application of renewable energy promotes climate protection.};
        
    \draw[->] (energy) (2.5,-3.25) -- (health.south);
    
    \draw[->] (energy) (5.5,-3.25) -- (education.south);
        
    \draw[->] (energy) (2.5,-4.75) -- (income.north);
    
    \draw[->] (energy) (5.5,-4.75) -- (environment.north);
 
\end{tikzpicture}
 
\end{document}
```